# Auto opening generated pdf file

Tags: scripts, pdf, xdg-open

My application generates pdf file and writes out to some folder. 
Is there any setup to automatically open it when its generated?

Comment: for a specific location? (or directory). If it is not a huge directory yes. Please mention it.

Comment: In my app's temp directory.

Comment: I will put in code a terminal command: xpdf filename.pdf

Comment: What programming language? Basic? ;)

Comment: How are you running your application? From the terminal? Which command are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Some applications offer to open the just created file, but if not:

Assuming your temp directory is a "flat" directory (without `.pdf` files in subdirectories) does not contain thousands of files (since it is a `temp` directory), the small background script will do the job.

It keeps an eye on the directory and opens *new* `.pdf` files with your default application to open `pdf` files.

#### How to use:

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `open_newpdf.py`
2. In the head section of the script, set the path to your directory
3. Test run it from a terminal window, type the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/open_newpdf.py
   ```

   Create a new `.pdf` file in your directory, it should open within 3 seconds.
4. If all works fine, add it to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import time
import subprocess

#--- set the absolute path to your directory below
dr = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test"
#---

ls1 = os.listdir(dr)
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    ls2 = os.listdir(dr)
    for item in ls2:
        if all([not item in ls1, item.endswith(".pdf")]):
            subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", dr+"/"+item])
    ls1 = ls2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler alternative. If you have a script that generates PDF files, then you can also make it run the following commands each time it creates a PDF file called `file.pdf`,

```
xdg-open file.pdf
```

which will open the file with the default application set to handle PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Create wrapper script `watch_pdf`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
if [ "${FILE##*.}" = "pdf" ]
then
echo "$2/$1"
    xdg-open "$2/$1"
fi
exit 0
```

make it executable:

```
chmod +x <path_of_watch_pdf>
```

Watch your folder:

```
inoticoming <your_tmp_folder> <path_of_watch_pdf> {} <your_tmp_folder> \;
```